# HTTP/Browser Caching with .htaccess

Tags: php, html, apache, apache2

I have a .htaccess in my root directory with the following setting.

```
<filesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=864000, public, must-revalidate"
</filesMatch>
```

I thought it caches any of the files in the filesmatch directive. One thing that I am not clear about is whether the browsers cache the actual HTML content that goes out (from index.php) or not. I don't want browsers to cache the HTML. I only want browsers to cache the images, css and js.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you are saying you are uncertain if the browser is caching your PHP file or what is generated from it, use these headers to be absolutely certain, you will never know unless you are explicitly setting rules for it:

```
header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); 
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate( 'D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT'); 
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate'); 
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false); 
header('Pragma: no-cache');
```

Comment: This is is independent of the image/js/css file cache settings in my apache/htaccess file right? I want browsers to cache those files.

Comment: Yes as long as you are not generating any images with PHP.